# 5.5.60-MariaDB mysql， Accidental appearance Lost connection to MySQL server at reading/sending authorization packet

Tags: mysql, mariadb

mysql Official documents Only containing “Lost connection to MySQL server at reading authorization packet” Solution， But it does not include “Lost connection to MySQL server at sending authorization packet system error: 32” method。 By setting “connect_timeout” invalid。

Setting the values of some variables cannot solve this problem

I hope everyone can provide a solution

Attempted set  max_connections connect_timeout  open_files max_allowed_packet 。Unable to solve this problem。

Comment: What is "Accidential appearance"? Do the server logs show MariaDB-5.5.60 still running? How are you connecting? Did you try [5.5.68](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-55-series/)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer，yes, MariaDB-5.5.60 still running。Multiple links to MySQL services may result in a loss of link issue。Sending/reading... appears Such a problem。The company's environment needs to be addressed in the MariaDB-5.5.60  version.

Comment: It's just strange, what kind of scenario triggers "sending authorization packet system error: 32" when linking MySQL，The official document does not provide a solution to this issue。

Comment: "perror 32" -> "OS error code  32:  Broken pipe" indicating the server closed down the connection. ""sending authorization packet system" isn't a message that the mysql client in 5.5.60 generates. Which is the client doing the connecting? What changed recently for this to show up now?

Comment: Using multiple threads, frequently linking databases, and using local variables as link handles, the occurrence of problems is highly accidental. I'm not sure which link will cause problems, bro, you can take a look at the screenshot of the log I uploaded.

Comment: There is no problem with user link information.

Comment: Did look - max_connections exceeded is a guess. `show global status like '%connect%'` on the server and include that by editing the question.

Comment: Thank you, the number of links has been detected during operation. And exceed 'max_connections' The abnormal error reported by the value is' too many connections'。

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This error is probably related to your `connect_timeout` setting, but it is really hard to follow what you have tried (*"By setting `connect_timeout` invalid"*, *"Setting the values of some variables cannot solve this problem"*) So to give us a better idea, can you please, as danblack asked, add the output of `show global status like '%connect%'` to your question (as text, not as screenshot, and not as an answer, but by editing your question). You should probably also remove your password from the screenshot (and maybe change it).